# How to remove a long alphanumeric pattern in R

Tags: gsub

I want to remove a 32 digit ID from a string. The ID is in 32 character/digit format separated by "-"

y <- c("abcd1234-ab12-cd12-1z12-abcd1234abcd6789 Print me I am ok")

What i need is the remaining part of the string "print me I am ok"

appreciate your help!

Comment: If all you really care about is the text that comes AFTER the first blank space character, then you can use the answer provided by @Brian `stringToTrim.Substring(IndexOf(" ") + 1)`, or if you know how many hyphens `-` there are you could also trim based on that `stringToTrim.Substring(33+num_of_hyphens)`

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
string stringToTrim = "abcd1234-ab12-cd12-1z12-abcd1234abcd6789 Print me I am ok";
string result = stringToTrim.Substring(IndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Comment: I was looking for a regex expression which can remove the 32 digit pattern. The 32 digit pattern can come anywhere in the string. Sorry if I was not very clear in the question..